# How to make shortcuts to existing apps (WP7)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm developing an app that shows the time, local weather and stuff like that..

The problem I have.. is I can't for the life of me find a way to create a shorcut to apps..

I'm trying to make shortcuts to launch existing apss like calculator, marketplace, whatsapp, etc.

Is this possible using button like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

and add content inside the brackets..??

I'm sort of a newbie so don't go all crazy on me.. :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launching other applications in Windows phone 7 Programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042353/launching-other-applications-in-windows-phone-7-programatically)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, but this generally isn't going to be possible under the current (and probably future) versions of the OS.  Apps run in a sandboxed environment, and aren't supposed to have access to those kind of things.

You can launch to some of the inbuilt tasks, such as Marketplace:

```
MarketplaceSearchTask marketplaceSearchTask = new MarketplaceSearchTask(); 
marketplaceSearchTask.SearchTerms = "games"; 
marketplaceSearchTask.Show();
```

But the number of tasks available are very limited.

Comment: Than I surely wonder how this Dev made it posible.. See following link: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1343993I already send him a private message.. but still no reply.. :-S

Comment: It appears that he is linking to things that are inbuilt, not other "apps" per se. He says that future versions will support marketplace apps, but, without using "illegal" API calls, I don't think he'll succeed.  Good luck to both him and you, though.

Comment: I surely miss the good old days when we had WM6.5 just because more things where possible.. never expected these kind of limitations.. I love WP7 because of the clean look.. but hate these apple policies that came with it..