# How do I programmatically launch an application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to programmatically call an event to launch an application in Windows Phone 7.  How do I go about doing this?

What I'm looking for is how do I schedule this event call? (for example, opening an app in WP7)?

Comment: What do you mean by 'call app'? Calling or opening an app is the OS function. Nothing to worry about your language, please elaborate your problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I mean opening an app from the phone :) And this opening should be scheduled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are talking about `Tasks`. All available tasks can be consulted here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks(v=vs.92).aspx

The call app you are talking about is the `PhoneCallTask`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.phonecalltask(v=vs.92).aspx

If you want to call and app, that is, to **open** an application from the phone, you can't really do it. Please look at: [Launching other applications in Windows phone 7 Programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042353/launching-other-applications-in-windows-phone-7-programatically)

Comment: I mean opening any app from the phone. And this opening should be scheduled. Thanks for answer, Timotei. Can I ask one more question? In  Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler namespace exists Alarm and Reminder classes. How i can override behavior and display notification (a window with buttons "snooze" and "dismiss"). It's possible?

Comment: That Alarm and Reminder classes are sealed. You cannot really customize the. But the Reminder contains the snooze and dismiss buttons by default. You just set the title, and contents.