# Downloading file from web in wp7 application

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Launching other applications in Windows phone 7 Programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042353/launching-other-applications-in-windows-phone-7-programatically)

I have created an application in which I download Images/Files and other docs from web for my application but I need them to open using their **default file launchers** like pdf should be opened via adobe pdf viewer.

Currently I have acheived this using external web browser using *webbrowsertask*. I want it to happen within the app using webclient or webbrowser control. I tried these two methods, they worked correctly for images and text files but failed for pdf. Is there any other method?

Windows 8 has a native function which launches the default file handler. Is there something similar in WP7?

Comment: If you open a pdf file in browser, browser should reroute you to Adobe Reader if it's installed. If it isn't - bad luck :)

Comment: browser takes only absolute URI as parameters. PDF file url will be local/relative and not absolute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link provided by Patrick say everything. You can't download and open files other than images and music files. Files like PDF/DOC need to be opened via webbrowsertask, so the file will fall into correct application's IsolatedStorage (for PDFs - Acrobat Reader). If you download the file, it will fall under your app's IsolatedStorage and Acrobat will not have access to that file.