# call another application inside windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

From what I've seen [Windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042353/launching-other-applications-in-windows-phone-7-programatically) couldn't call other applications form inside your application. Is this still the case?

Just wanting to call another application from inside my application? is this possible and if so, can someone point me in the right direction?

Much appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 3):

As of Windows Phone 7.8, inter-app communication is still unavailable. It's also unlikely to be introduced in a future 7.x version.

In Windows Phone 8, you can add a `Extensions/Protocol` element to your WMAppManifest to reserve a URI prefix that can then be launched from another app using the [`Launcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/br241801.aspx) class.

For more information, see MSDN:

> [Auto-launching apps using file and URI associations for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)